# Writing SQL where clause to exclude rows based on two conditions

Tags: sql, where-clause

Hi there I have a database where I would like Select all rows, but excluding records where two conditions are both met. I can't work out how to write the where clause that does this.

To give an example the table is:

```
Name | Date | Country
```

I want to select all rows except rows where the Name is Dave and the Date is > 20180101. So rows where the Name is Dave but the Date is <= 20180201 should be included as should rows where the date is > 20180101 and the name is anything but Dave.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, which version of SQL are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Etc.

Comment: First question:  Have you even attempted to write it yourself???  If you have, where is it????  Otherwise, start writing.

Answer (score 1):

This is where [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is helpful. It states `!(A && B)` can also be expressed `!A || !B` and vice versa: `!A || !B` can be `!(A && B)`.
Also that `!(A || B)` is `!A && !B` and `!A && !B` is `!(A || B)`.

For this question you want: `NOT ('Dave' AND >'20180101')`, which matches the first case above. Applying De Morgan's Law would give you `NOT 'Dave' OR <='20180101'`.

Use it in an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE [Name] <> 'Dave' OR [Date] <= '20180101'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table
where name <> 'Dave' OR date <= '2018-01-01'
```

get all the rows that the name is not dave or the date is not X. if both conditions are fail (both dave and X) then that row won't be returned.

Comment: The inverse of `>'2018-01-01'` is `<='2018-01-01'` rather than `<>'2018-01-01'`